# Company name on iOS Setting page

Tags: ios, xcode, settings

After a long search I didn't find anything that explains how this work.

Anyone knows, how to set Company name to our app So that it can be visible on the iOS Settings page.

I think that certificate name doesn't linked to this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to set the company name in the iOS settings page.

Answer (score -1):

The company name is set when you created your Apple developer account. I don't believe it can be changed with contacting Apple and going through a manual process with them. Also, it cannot be specified per app, but rather applies to all apps from an organization.

Comment: But our company name doesn't visible on App Details. I don't know why.

Comment: Would the person who is down voting these answers care to share their answer with the class?